# How to modify legend count selection criteria?

Tags: microsoft-visio, microsoft-visio-2013

I have a Visio diagram that has around 20 server shapes on it. 5 of these I have colored a different color as they are a different environment.

When I drag and drop the legend it counts the servers as the same thing.

1. I tried modifying the Prop.ShapeType = "Server2" but that didn't seem to do anything. What do I need to do to get these servers counted as separate counts in the legend?
2. Is there a way to specify a specific attribute to count on, such as color or is it only by name (or some similar attribute)?

It would be great if the solution includes steps for replication purposes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't like being the bearer of bad news but there is no way to change how the Legend shape works. There are no settings.

It counts shapes with the same master name, so try saving your special server shape to a new stencil and change the shape's name. `More Shapes -> New Stencil` then copy and paste the shape into the new stencil. See if that makes the legend shape count differently.

Comment: Thanks for the note Paul. Can you provide the breadcrumbs on how to save as a new stencil from one of the default shapes? Thanks!

Comment: More Shapes -> New Stencil then copy and paste the shape into the new stencil.

Comment: This worked perfectly. I wish they would add a way to modify the look of the legend such as removal of the subtitle for example. Thanks for the answer.